# Adding ControlParameter to SqlDataSource prevents query and databinding?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, sqldatasource, controlparameter

I have a SqlDataSource that calls a stored procedure and it works fine. If I add a `<ControlParameter>` tag to add an additional argument, then the query never fires and the databinding never occurs. Suggestions?

**This works**:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultDB %>"
    SelectCommand="SP_WHATEVER" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    UpdateCommand="SP_WHATEVER2" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="UserName" SessionField="RP_Program" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <snip...>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**When I add the ControlParameter, the databinding no longer occurs**:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultDB %>"
    SelectCommand="SP_WHATEVER" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    UpdateCommand="SP_WHATEVER2" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="" Name="UserName" SessionField="RP_Program" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="SprocArgName" ControlID="ddlFilter" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <snip...>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The ControlParameter refers to a valid object on the page. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely one of the parameter is empty or null. Add CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false" to the asp:SqlDataSource and ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" to both parameters. Once it works, tweak the parameters so that SP gets what it expects.

Comment: "CancelSelectOnNullParameter" was exactly what I was missing. Amazing that I searched Google 4 or 5 different ways and couldn't find that; hopefully this question will help the next person with the same issue!

Comment: Thanks this worked for me as well. Wrecking my brains for past few days. Surprisingly it works without that attribute in some my previous aspx files but not on a new one I just created.

Comment: I spend one hour trying to solve this....